# SocketIO Presence System Redis

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, socket.io-redis

I'm building a presence system for live streaming using Socket.IO with Redis, with load balanced instances.
Everytime the user enters a room, I send to the server a socket.emit('join', roomId) and the server joins the user to the corresponding room.
Every minute, I refresh my dashboard and get all the users connected to the instance by using the redis adapter like this:

```
io.of('/').adapter.clients([req.params.name], (err, clients) => {
        console.log(clients.length); // an array containing all connected socket ids
        if (req.query.detail) {
            res.send(clients);
        } else {
            res.send({onlineUsers: clients.length});
        }
    });
```

If one of my servers goes down, Redis automatically removes all the connected sockets and refreshes almost instantaneously the number of sockets in that room.

Now the problem:
Whenever the user connects, I call

```
io.of('/').on('connection', function (socket) {
    //.. set user Online in database
});
```

for setting the user online.

And when the user disconnects I do

```
io.of('/').on('disconnect', function (socket) {
    //... Set user offline
});
```

The problem is...
If my server goes down for a while, the user will be marked as Online forever.
Seen that I have more than 20k people online, it's almost impossible to send every minute a request to the server update the database with a LastSeen, because this would cause more than 300 writes/sec (I don't think mongodb will handle, will it ?)

Is there any how to solve this problem? Use redis to store some data in case the server goes offline for a while, I recover the last state ? How could that happen?

Is there any solution for this ? Even if socketio retries to reconnect, what if the server goes offline for 1 minute and the user leaves, he'll be online forever.

THANK YOU !

Comment: Please have you gotten any solution? Do you not mind sharing?